# Finding the set {$ a\ |\ \mathrm{gcd}(a, b) = 1$}

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility

I was wondering about the method to determine the set {$ a \ |\  \mathrm{gcd}(a, b) = 1$} : what is the faster way to get it ?

I was thinking about to compute it like the sieve of Eratosthenes : test if $\mathrm{gcd}(i, b) \not= 1$, in that case we will not test numbers which are a multiple of $i$ etc ...

Can I be more effective ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You only need to do it once for each prime appearing in the prime factorisation of $b$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand your answer, what should I test with primes factors of b ?

Comment: $\gcd(a,b) > 1$ if and only if there is a prime dividing both, $a$ and $b$. So you only need to mark multiples of primes dividing $b$ to find all $a$ with $\gcd(a,b) > 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is clear for me now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine the positive integers $k$ less than $b$ which are relatively prime to $b$. Then the set of equivalence classes $k$ modulo $b$ describes the set of all integers relatively prime to $k$. The equivalence class $k$ modulo $b$ is $\{k + mb : m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. This works because $k + mb$ is relatively prime to $b$ if and only if $k$ is relatively prime to $b$.

For example, we have that the set of odd integers (i.e. the set of numbers relatively prime to $2$) is described as $\{ n \in \mathbb{Z} : n \equiv 1 \mod 2 \}$.